# How to control processing of AMPScript using execution context: Name

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

According to the [**documentation**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/executionContext.htm) and [**The AMPScript Guide**](https://ampscript.guide/script-blocks/), it should be possible to control whether code in an AMPScript Block is interpreted by using a name for the script block.

I am aware of the known bug that the system variable `@@ExecCtx` (execution context) is currently always "Load".

So controlling script interpretation based on `GET` / `POST` method won't work at this stage- fine.

My question is - how should it work to specify a name?

Let's go with the example from the docs:

> In this example, the UpsertData command executes only if the caller's execution context is set to POST and the name UpdateDate is specified:

```
%%[
/* note I fixed a typo in the documentation, there was a " missing */
[name="UpdateDate";type="Post"]
UpsertData("MyDE","Col1",Val1,"Col2",Val2)
]%%
```

Sounds interesting, but what is meant by 'specifying the name "UpdateDate"'? 
To my understanding, I basically gave this content block a name now. 
(plus, I said it should only run when POSTed to, which does not currently work)

Where/how am I expected to specify the name? 
So far I tried:

- sending along name = UpdateDate in a `POST` request payload to the CloudPage that the code runs on
- sending along name = UpdateDate in a `POST` request parameter to the CloudPage

Both with no visible effect.

Comment: are you need to update the data or can you please explain clearly

Comment: There is no particular usecase to solve, I just want to understand the documentation and reproduce how the example given there is meant to work.

Comment: It used to work by including `<input type="hidden" name="__contextName" id="__contextName" value="myform" />` in your form, but that was with Microsites. Did a quick test and it doesn't work with Cloudpages.